# Optimized paging query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, pagination

I am trying to optimize a paging query for my query with total count of records in a stored procedure. Please give some optimized paging query to fetch 25 records per page from millions of records.

DDL Commands

```
create table pdf_details
(
     prodid nvarchar(100), 
     prodname nvarchar(100),
     lang nvarchar(100),
     fmt nvarchar(5),
     type varchar(2) 

     constraint pk_pdf Primary Key (proid, lang, fmt)
)

create table html_details
(
     prodid nvarchar(100),
     prodname nvarchar(100),
     lang nvarchar(100),
     fmt nvarchar(5),
     type varchar(2)

     constraint pk_html Primary Key(prodid, lang, fmt)
)

create index ix_pdf_details on pdf_details(prodname)
```

Sample records

```
insert into pdf_details 
values ('A100', 'X', 'EN', 'HM', 'PDF'),
       ('A100', 'X', 'JP', 'GM', 'PDF'),
       ('A100', 'X', 'EN', 'HM', 'PDF'),
       ('B101', 'Y', 'EN', 'HM', 'PDF');

insert into html_details 
values ('B100', 'X', 'EN', 'HM', 'HTML')
       ('B100', 'X', 'JP', 'GM', 'HTML')
       ('B100', 'X', 'EN', 'HM', 'HTML')
       ('C101', 'Y', 'EN', 'GH', 'HTML')
```

In reality, these tables contain millions of rows.

Original query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    TP.PRODID AS ID,
    TP.PRODNAME AS NAME,
    TP.LANG AS LANG,
    TP.FMT,
    TP.TYPE
FROM
    PDF_DETAILS TP
WHERE 
    TP.PRODID = @PRODID
    AND (@PRODUCTNAME IS NULL OR 
         REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TP.PRODNAME, '™', '|TM'), '®', '|TS'), '©', '|CP'), '°', '|DEG')
            LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@PRODNAME, '[', '\['), '_', '\_'), '™', '|TM'), '®', '|TS'), '©', '|CP'), '°', '|DEG') ESCAPE '\' 

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT 
    TP.PRODID AS ID,
    TP.PRODNAME AS NAME,
    TP.LANG AS LANG,
    TP.FMT,
    TP.TYPE
FROM 
    HTML_DETAILS TP
WHERE 
    TP.PRODID = @PRODID
    AND (@PRODUCTNAME IS NULL OR 
            REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TP.PRODNAME,'™','|TM'),'®','|TS'),'©','|CP'),'°','|DEG')
LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@PRODNAME,'[','\['),'_','\_'),'™','|TM'),'®','|TS'),'©','|CP'),'°','|DEG') ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: You should add *what* constraint those `pk_pdf` etc. are - you just say "constraint" - nothing more - what are you trying to create here?? And why do you have **two tables** of identical structure?? What's the point?? Why not just **one** table, and separate the PDF from the HTML files by means of the `type` column? That would make that crazy SELECT somewhat easier, too!

Comment: it is composite primary key.Now i updated in the post.I mentioned some important columns in select list from both tables.But Html table contains some extra columns.so structure will be different.

Answer (score 2):

As of SQL Server **2012**, you can use the `OFFSET ... FETCH` approach to paging - you Google for it, there are **TONS** of great articles about it.

Basically, you have to do something like this:

```
SELECT (list-of-columns)
FROM YourTable
(optionally add JOINs here)
WHERE (conditions)
ORDER BY (some column)
      OFFSET n ROWS
      FETCH NEXT y ROWS ONLY
```

Basically, you must have an `ORDER BY` (since offsetting / skipping only makes sense when you know what your data is ordered by), and then you can define with the `OFFSET` clause (with a fixed number of a SQL Server variable `@offset`) how many rows (in that defined ordering) to skip, and the `FETCH NEXT` clause (again with a fixed number of a SQL Server variable `@numrows`) defines how many rows will be returned.

Comment: I think we cannot use single select statement for my query because it contains union all operator.any optimized paging method for this union all operator with total count.